# php call nested function

Tags: php, function, laravel

i wonder how php can achieve like below function design:

Class->func()->func()

Here is the laravel validate example.

```
    $validator->after(function($validator) 
    {
        if ($this->somethingElseIsInvalid()) 
        {
            **$validator->errors()->add('field', 'Something is wrong with this field!');**
        }
    });
```

Is the after() do the magic work here?

And how to create my own code that can behave like this.

Comment: In your methods you can do `return $this;` which returns the object and gives you the possibility to do `class->func()->func()->func()`

Comment: @Neat thanks and it's call method Chaining, learn somethings new today : )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Its called Method Chaining.**

Method chaining works because a function or a method of the class always returns object which further call another function.

Basically it returns it self.

Ex:

```
public function method1() {
    // method content ...
    return $this;
}

public function method2() {
    // method content ...
    return $this;
}
```

Please refer the following link to read more on Method Chaining,

http://www.techflirt.com/tutorials/oop-in-php/php-method-chaining.html

There will be more articles you could find on this.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @limonte, Thanks for the comment. I updated my answer. Your comments are most welcome!

Answer (score 3):

You need to return the object you want to chain the next method to.

```
public function chain() {
    return $this;
}
```

Sometimes this will be the current class ($this), somethings this will be an instance of another class depending on what is appropriate.